# php how to unit 2 fulltext search and order by date?

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

I want to make a fulltext search, there are 2 group search query, one search match word 'Harry' and 'potter', second search query only match word 'Rowling'. How to unit them and `order dy date`? Then  `$query1 relevance is 70%`,  `$query1 relevance is 30%`? Thanks.

```
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE MATCH (title,content) AGAINST ('+Harry +potter' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";//all the articles both match word 'Harry' and 'potter'
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE MATCH (title,content) AGAINST ('+Rowling' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";//all the articles macth 'Rowling'
```

Comment: @Charles, how to combine `SELECT FROM LEFT JOIN ON WHERE` and SELECT FROM MATCH AGAINST`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both your queries select rows from the same table and the same columns set. What about UNION?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE MATCH (title,content) AGAINST ('+Harry +potter' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
UNION
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE MATCH (title,content) AGAINST ('+Rowling' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
```